# Selective serialization with SubSonic generated classes

Tags: c#, serialization, mono, subsonic

I've been using SubSonic 2 for a while now, but as I am starting a new project, I'd like to upgrade to 3. In my old project, I used a custom, non-sustainable hack to serialize things for web services. I really would like to find a more elegant solution.

I'm using Mono, so I need to stay within implemented classes, e.g. DataContractSerializer is probably out. Still on ASMX, though would love to upgrade to WCF as soon as the support is solid. Moonlight/Silverlight will be the initial clients. JSON/protobuf in the future...

The standard Xml serializer is opt-out, so I'd need some way to take control of it. Which brings me to IXmlSerializable. I'm rather unfamiliar with SS's templates, but it seems that editing these would allow me to generate the serialization code necessary to not touch the rest of the hierarchy chain. Is this a "good idea"?

I'd love to just use SS's POCO support, but I don't think it supports complex types or arrays.

Other thoughts/options?

Answer (score 1):

`IXmlSerializable` is IMO more than a little awkward to get right. Note that if you are handling the `XmlSerializer` code yourself you can override everything at runtime by using the constructor that accepts `XmlAttributeOverrides` (but if you use this you should cache and re-use the `XmlSerializer` instance, or it will leak like a sieve).

You briefly mention `protobuf`; note that `protobuf-net` (even in v1) allows you to add member-level serialization data at the *type* level, so you can include that information in a partial class alongside a generated type:

```
// file 1
partial class GeneratedClass
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
// file 2
[ProtoPartialMember(1, "Foo")]
[ProtoPartialIgnore("Bar")]
partial class GeneratedClass {}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, big fan of your protobuf implementation, crazy fast. Though I can control the serialization manually, the endgame is that other people could consume the web services as well. I was hoping to have a more automagic approach, e.g. the user is presented with an XSD/WSDL which has no mention of the rest of the SS hierarchy. Then they generate their classes from it and so on.

Comment: @joe - in that case, I would recommend simply creating a separate DTO layer that is *similar* to the SS types, but under your direct command.

Comment: That was my original workaround. :) Though I did do it by hand, which is what I meant by unsustainable. I suppose it could be rather automatic with SS templates eh? I'll try this out and post the results.